# Conditional distribution of two Gaussians given one is larger.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Given two Gaussian random variables $Z:=(Z_1,Z_2)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, is there an explicit distribution for $Z$ conditioned on $Z_1>Z_2$? Is it still Gaussian? I know $\mathbb{P}[Z_1>Z_2]$ has an explicit expression which led me to believe maybe $(Z|Z_1>Z_2)$ has an explicit expression too.

For example, using $\Sigma=[[1, 0.5],[0.5, 1]]$ and plotting the histograms of the conditioned $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, they look Gaussian to me.

Picture of $Z_1|Z_1>Z_2$:

[image]

Picture of $Z_2|Z_1>Z_2$:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Z = (Z_1,Z_2)$ has a bivariate Gaussian density whose support is the entire plane.  Conditioned on $Z_1>Z_2$, the conditional density of $Z$ has support only a half-plane and so the conditional density of $Z$ is very definitely *not* bivariate Gaussian.  But it is entirely possible for two marginally Gaussian random variables to have joint density function that is *not* a bivariate Gaussian density.  Indeed, as user [cardinal over on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633) remarks

> The bivariate normal distribution is the exception, not the rule!

when two random variables are marginally Gaussian (normal) and he provides numerous examples to back up his assertion.